# Show a fragment with shared elements animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions, fragmenttransaction, shared-element-transition

In my app I have code like this:

```
final FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "tag");
transaction.addSharedElement(view, "transitionName");
transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

It works fine, shared elements animation works.
But if I change this code like

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "tag")
                .hide(fragment)
                .commit();

final FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.remove(oldFragment);
transaction.show(fragment);
transaction.addSharedElement(view, "transitionName");
transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

Shared elements animation is not working here. But on d.android.com [it is written](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addSharedElement(android.view.View,%20java.lang.String)) that addSharedElement "Used with to map a View from a removed or hidden Fragment to a View from a **shown** or added Fragment." So is it a bug or I am doing wrong something?

Comment: also facing same issue, I tried with add and hide which removes transition.

Comment: me too .. any solutions ?

Comment: me too. It works with add and remove. Changing to add and hide don't works. Even if I change the order of add/remove in the same transaction